# Facebook login popup in unity, How to setup

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-unity-sdk

I want to get Facebook login popup in my unity wenplayer game idont know where set this scripts .
i uploaded my games on dropbox in my pc and add this code to my html page.

i use this code on html file of dropbox.
https://github.com/nabeelsaleem/fb-login-html/blob/master/Code%20to%20login

i am not getting login popup appear, but i use same code in my blog and it works here: hashtaginside.blogspot.com